# Wordpress admin_post callback not firing

Tags: php, wordpress

This seems to be working on other sites I create however, my callback doesn't seem to fire. All I get is a white screen. Its like the callback does not exists.

I have checked has_action('admin_post_process_submission') and that returns true.

The plugin file itself returns other functionality absolutely fine.

I've been staring at JS for the last week or two so is there something I'm missing?

```
<?php class KnpvForm extends KnpvEndPoints {

function __construct()  {

    parent::__construct();

    //Actions for processing the form <<< does not seem
    add_action( 'admin_post_process_submission', array($this, 'knpv_admin_process_submission'));        

    //A filter which seems to work fine.
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', array($this, 'knpv_mce_butttons'), 10, 2 );

}

/**
 * I expect this function to just print some words. 
 */
public function knpv_admin_process_submission(){

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r('some words');
    echo '</pre>';

}

} ?>
```

Comment: `public function knpv_admin_process_submission(){ob_start(); echo 'Test';return ob_get_clean();}`

Comment: Nope, same thing.

Comment: Prints test if I call that function from within __construct. And if I call that function from within other functions.

Comment: has_action('admin_post_process_submission', array($this, 'knpv_process_submission')); returns 10.